# Yeoman cucumberjs

Tags: yeoman, cucumberjs

Hi I am learning to use cucumberjs on ember.
Using yeoman for it.
when I try to run cucumberjs from command prompt I get below error

```
 $ grunt cucumberjs 
No "cucumberjs" targets found.Warning: Task "cucumberjs" failed. Use --force to continue.
Aborted due to warnings.
```

Comment: Whats your `Gruntfile.js` look like?

Comment: thanks for the pointer got it fixed in gruntInit ----                cucumberjs: {
            src: yeomanConfig.test + '/features/',
            options: {
                steps: yeomanConfig.test + '/features/step_definitions'
            }
        } and in ---- var yeomanConfig = {
        app: 'app',
        dist: 'dist',
        test: 'test'
    };